# full width list items grid bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the latest version of [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/).

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <ul id="grid">
      <li class="mix dogs col-sm-3"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="..."></li>
      <li class="mix cats col-sm-3"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="..."></li>
      <li class="mix krakens col-sm-3"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="..."></li>
      <li class="mix dogs cats col-sm-3"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="..."></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the output is not quite what I'm expecting, it adds a horizontal scrollbar and also the spacing is not equal on on the first item and last item.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

I want to have this output: 
[image]

Is it possible with the actual grid system to remove the gutters between list items and make them fill the width of the browser ?

Comment: do you want the gutters removed for just this set of elements, or for everything?

Comment: just for this set of elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

There's no such thing as a ul.grid inside a .row it won't clear and the ul has margins and padding on it. Do the following:

## http://jsbin.com/getof/1/edit

**For a standard set up with gutter:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="mix dogs col-sm-3"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="..."></div>
      <div class="mix cats col-sm-3"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="..."></div>
      <div class="mix krakens col-sm-3"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="..."></div>
      <div class="mix dogs cats col-sm-3"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="..."></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**For no gutter do the following:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row flush-col">
      <div class="mix dogs col-sm-3"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="..."></div>
      <div class="mix cats col-sm-3"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="..."></div>
      <div class="mix krakens col-sm-3"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="..."></div>
      <div class="mix dogs cats col-sm-3"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="..."></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**New CSS:**

```
.row.flush-col > [class*="col-"] {padding:0;}

.img-fluid {width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the gutter if you are using LESS. You will have to make it a column from inside your styles instead of adding the `col` class to the element.

See official steps with LESS mixins in the documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-less